# Alternative approach to comparing standardized samples

Tags: standardization, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

In my dataset I believe two factors (say 'elevation' and 'number of neighbours') affect a parameter ('A') under investigation.

I took two subsets of the data (10 points with high A and 10 points with minimal A) and I would like to check whether the combination elevation:neighbours is significantly different for the low A subset compared to the high A subset.

Elevation and neighbours are parameters on a very different scale. My plan was to combine them into one parameter by standardizing both (x-mean_x/sd) and then add them up. I'd do this for subset highA and subset lowA.

Then I planned to do a kolmogorov-smirnov test to check whether both samples come from different distributions. I though they would, but they obviously don't because I standardized my data.

What's another approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you considered a regression model?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to use my whole dataset for this because I believe the combination effect is only present for points with exceptionally high A.

Comment: Actually I'm not interested in the regression model. I don't really care whether the effect applies to the full range of the data (I will be in a later stage). For now I'd just like to say that the factor elevation:neigbour is very different for the points with exceptionally high A.

Comment: Although you use the language of "significance," this sounds like an exploratory exercise.  Why not then look at scatterplots of the two factors, one for each level of $A$, and see precisely *how* they differ?

Comment: I _know_ how they differ: for high A the elevation is high and the number of neighbours is low. For low A it's exactly the opposite. I just want to be able to say more than "through visual analysis it was observed that". I want the 'p'. ;)

Comment: The p-value will be incorrect if the hypothesis was formulated as a consequence of reviewing the data.  You might consider quantifying the differences between the two groups.  "Through visual analysis it was observed" is an honest portrayal of what you have done.

Comment: So keep it at: elevation/neighbours ranged between [x and y] for highA whereas it ranged between [a and b] for low A. Full stop. No 'these ranges' are _significantly_ different... ?

Comment: You can use other descriptive statistics than ranges, such as means, quartiles, standard deviations, correlation coefficients, and so on.  But due to the subjectivity involved in formulating the hypothesis from the data themselves, it's not possible to compute a p-value or assess significance.